# What technique does VLC use to grab Youtube streams?

Tags: youtube, vlc

I have a Youtube player written in VB.net and I currently rely on the Youtube SWF URL `www.youtube.com/v/{Video-id}`, but I find this causes issues with speed. So I was thinking of passing streams straight into Windows Media Player.

I have been looking through the VLC source code to find how they automate the process, but to no avail.

So what process does VLC automate in their code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC uses a LUA script to find the actual streaming MRL.

If you look in the VLC source code, the script is located here:

```
vlc/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua
```

This script scrapes the HTML page at the YouTube "watch" URL looking for particular elements.

It's brittle of course, since YouTube can (and do from time to time) change their page layout. When this happens, you need to wait for a new release of VLC after someone provides a fix to the LUA script.